# How to fix Google Lighthouse 'Links are not crawlable' error

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have the error on PageSpeed Links not crawlable. The code is an accordian which opens and closes using the data-bs-target="#faq-list-1" in Bootstrap. Please advise how I could make crawlable, to comply? The message from Page speed is: What is a stairlift?

```
<a data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="collapse" data-bs-target="faq-list-1">
```

Full Div for this part of the Accordian:

```
<!--  <div class="faq-list"> <ul> <li data-aos="fade-up"> <i class="bx bx-help-circle icon-help"></i> <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="collapse" data-bs-target="#faq-list-1">What is a stairlift?<i class="bx bx-chevron-down icon-show"></i><i class="bx bx-chevron-up icon-close"></i></a> <div id="faq-list-1" class="collapse show" data-bs-parent=".faq-list"> <p> A stairlift is like a personal lift for your stairs. It helps people who have trouble walking up and down stairs to do so safely and easily. You would normally sit on it, and it will carry you up or down the staircase. </p> </div> </li>  -->
```

'I tried'

```
<!--  <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="collapse" data-bs-target="https://stairlifts-hereford.com//#faq-list-1">  -->
```